# Django-admin , show image Thumbnail in Admin Inline ( ChangeForm)

Tags: django, django-admin

I have several images  attached to an obj, and i want to show all the images in a small box.

**Models 1**

```
class Model1(models.Model):
  ........
```

**Model 2**

```html
class Imagem(models.Model):
    model1 = models.ForeignKey(Avaria)
    imagem = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image, blank=True, null=True)
```

**Models 1.ADMIN**

```html
class ImagemInline(admin.StackedInline):

    model = Imagem
    extra = 0
    max_num = 3    

class Moddel1Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  inlines = [ImagemInline]
```

Comment: i have a several images , that is not include inside the `model1`, that is not working for me

Comment: Do you want to display in list or detail page?

Comment: i want to show the image , i have this http://prntscr.com/mwpckp , and i just want to show the images.

Comment: This has been answered here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44025254/display-thumbnail-in-django-admin-inline/44051507